# Flag Interpretation

Tags: knowledge, pattern, geography, flags

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #16: Restricted Title: xkcd 2000-2500](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7528/monthly-topic-challenge-16-restricted-title-xkcd-2000-2500).</sub>

---

A UN member state recently raised a motion at a general meeting saying that they wished to change their national flag and were open to suggestions. A taskforce of 10 other nations was promptly established to assist: Belgium, Côte d'Ivoire, France, Guinea, Ireland, Italy, Mali, Nigeria, Peru, and Romania.

The state in question suggested that it might be nice to include an image on the new design - something that brought great enthusiasm from each of the taskforce members, and each of them made a... er... *helpful* suggestion, each one sillier than the last.

> "How about something reflecting the natural world - somewhere an animal might live, perhaps?"
> "Nah, you want to show off humanity's achievements - have a picture of a huge man-made structure!"
> "Or a person who's just crossed the finish line at a marathon."
> "Far too serious - go for something CRAZY...!"
> "Like a cartoon dog..."
> "Or a Simpsons character..."
> "Or a Simpsons voice artist!"
> "What about a great big picture of Ryan Gosling?!"
> "Or one of my father?"
> "No, one of my grandmother!"

Once everyone had had their fun, the taskforce members knuckled down and came up with a suggestion without any images at all, just a series of seven coloured stripes - green, yellow, red, orange, white, blue, and black - and everybody was satisfied.

[image: Flag of 7 vertical bands of different colours]

> **TASK: Identify the UN member state whose flag has been re-designed, and match up the taskforce members to their suggestions.**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The UN member state whose flag has been re-designed is

> DENMARK!

First we note that

> the title is Flag Interpretation. So we look at all the countries' flags and they are all tricolors:
>  ⬛️       Belgium
>  ⬜️       Côte d'Ivoire
>  ⬜️       France
>         Guinea
>  ⬜️       Ireland
>  ⬜️       Italy
>         Mali
>  ⬜️       Nigeria
>  ⬜️       Peru
>         Romania

Then we look at their suggestions and notice that

> "Or one of my father?" could be **DAD** and "No, one of my grandmother!" could be **NAN**. There are two flags that that have the same color on the left and right and they both have the same color in the center: ⬜️ Nigeria and ⬜️ Peru.

If we

> substitute A for white, D for green, and N for red, then we can solve the rest of the clues:
>  **`DEN`**     Mali: “How about something reflecting the natural world - somewhere an animal might live, perhaps?"
>  **`DAM`**    ⬜️ Ireland: "Nah, you want to show off humanity's achievements - have a picture of a huge man-made structure!"
>  **`RAN`**    ⬜️ France: "Or a person who's just crossed the finish line at a marathon."
>  **`MAD`**    ⬜️ Côte d'Ivoire: "Far too serious - go for something CRAZY...!"
>  **[`REN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren_and_Stimpy_(characters)#Ren_H%C3%B6ek)**    Romania: "Like a cartoon dog..."
>  **[`NED`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ned_Flanders)**    Guinea: "Or a Simpsons character..."
>  **[`DAN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dan_Castellaneta)**   ⬜️ Italy: "Or a Simpsons voice artist!"
>  **[`KEN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barbie_(film)#Cast)**   ⬛️ Belgium: "What about a great big picture of Ryan Gosling?!"
>  **`DAD`**    ⬜️ Nigeria: "Or one of my father?"
>  **`NAN`**    ⬜️ Peru: "No, one of my grandmother!"

Then the re-designed flag

> spells Denmark.
>     D
>     E
>     N
>     M
>  ⬜️   A
>     R
>  ⬛️   K

Comment: Someone please let me know if the color emojis don't show up.

Comment: I'm on Arch Linux and the `noto-fonts-emoji` package is installed, but the color emojis appear as B+W patterned squares. I resolved the issue by installing the `noto-color-emoji-fontconfig` package from AUR.